# How to document.write then after a delay document.write again

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to do document.write for one thing. Then delay for half a second and then document.write some more. Do you know if this is possible? And, if so, how? I've tried this so far and it hasn't worked:

```
document.write("Hello!");
setTimeout(function(){
    },1000);
document.write("hello!");
```

Comment: If possible, do not do `document.write`, it is shunned technique (add elements to body using jQuery, for example: `$('body').append('<p>Hello!</p>')`).

Comment: @herby Why not native `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello!'))`?

Comment: @PaulS. Whatever that modifies DOM through API. I am not using (nor giving time and energy to learn) native API since it is tricky doing cross-browser; I am relying on libraries (that is, jQuery/zepto was enough for me, it does the trick finely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the statement inside the setTimeout as such.

```
document.write("Hello!");

setTimeout(function(){
   document.write("hello!");
},1000);
```

The first parameter in [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) is a function you want to execute after delay milliseconds.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfRsK/1/) example (not using document.write)

Comment: Might be worth noting that if the page has finished being written to, [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) calls [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open), which will clear the page.

Comment: @Jarek you forgot remove `}` from last line.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't the way I was planning to do it, but that works perfectly! (I'd rate up if I could, but reputation :( Sorry...)

Comment: @WooCaSh if you start it after the page has finished loading, it will clear the page then (as `document.close` isn't called) both parts will appear. If you run it before the page has finished loading, if the page finishes before the timeout, the second `document.write` will clear the page, giving you just `"hello!"`.

Comment: @PaulS. Good point about what happens when using document.write. I just wanted to point out where his logic was wrong. Ideally he shouldn't be using it anyway as others have mentioned.

Comment: @PaulS. Oh now I understand what you mean. Thanks for it. I'm still learn new things :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some miliseconds to see the difference.
1000 ms = 1 second

And you nedd to add some code into your setTimeout function, as this:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hello")},3000);
```

SetTimeOut is not a "pause". It will execute his own code after a time.

Look at this example: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing1

Comment: Do you even look on his code? You say it's good? Do you try fire his code? I don't think so.

Comment: I know. I edited my comment when I see this, but you put me a -1 before I send my corrections

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var docWriteLater = function(){
   document.write("Hello Later!");   
}

setTimeout(docWriteLater, 1000)

document.write("hello now!");
```

Comment: That will overwrite the then-loaded page.